# Is there way to switch the HTML controller on the Airconsole object?

Tags: javascript, html, airconsole

Issue: 
I want to changed the controller.html to, let says myNewController.html, when I switch to a different scene.unity file.

Example: 
I have 2 mini games in the same project.  I'm playing GAME_1 with controller.html and I have completed the goal for GAME_1 and its switches me to GAME_2, which will require me to use a different controller layout hence myNewController.html.

What I Know:
When the scene switched it immediately throws the GAME_1's Airconsole object into GAME_2 and keeps using GAME_1's controller.html file.

Snippets of Code:
This script is attached the AirConsole Object that I created

public class What_Level : MonoBehaviour {
AirConsole console;

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    console = GetComponent<AirConsole> ();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    whatScene (Application.loadedLevel);
}

void whatScene(int levelNumber){
    if (levelNumber == 1) {
        Debug.Log ("Were in the GAME_1);
        //use some code to change the HTML file for GAME_1
    } else if (levelNumber == 2) {
        Debug.Log("We're in GAME_2");
        //use some code to change the HTML file for GAME_2
    }
}
```

}

The only function that the variable "console" that makes any sense is console.controllerHtml.  The description it gives in "public Object controllerHtml"

Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated and/or a reference page to the options I have for using on the AirConsole variable "console" would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning changing the controller layout. Instead of changing the file, just change the displayed content in the controller.html

E.g. you can make a  container element for each gamepad you want to show. And then broadcast a message to all controllers when they should change the visibility of the containers.

For example in your controller.html:

```
<div id="gamepad-1">Controller 1 stuff here ...</div>
<div id="gamepad-2">Controller 2 stuff here ...</div>
```

In javascript (also controller.html)

```
var container_1 = document.getElementById('gamepad-1');
var container_2 = document.getElementById('gamepad-2');
// Show or hide containers like (general function would be better :)
container_2.style.display = 'none';
container_1.style.display = 'block';
```

Now you just need to let your controllers know when to show/hide which container. You can do this by listening to onDeviceStateChange events.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to Airconsole so thanks for the insightful response.  I understand up to the very last part you have: 

Now you just need to let your controllers know when to show/hide which container. You can do this by onMessage or listening to onDeviceStateChange events

Are you referring to the onMessage in the controller.html file or the logic c-sharp file like in the pong game (https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-unity-plugin/blob/master/Assets/AirConsole/examples/pong/ExamplePongLogic.cs).

Could I not make, let says the start button, toggle this? or would this cause problems?

Comment: Well basically both. Your game (unity code) needs to tell the controller when to display which container-div. This means you can for example use .setCustomDeviceState({container: "gamepad-1"}) in unity and then in your controller listen with onDeviceStateChange() and check the custom data. I am currently building s.t. for handling views (not 100% done yet): github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-view-manager but maybe it helps you if you look at the code :)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll surely study it to thoroughly understand what is happening between the communication of Unity and the controller.html.  We'll see how I do in a few days :)